# My retina avatar is no longer retina

Tags: support, users, images

For some time now, I've had a retina avatar, but no longer.

I didn't change anything, but for apparently no reason my avatar is now very pixelated everywhere but my profile (and the top bar because it's scaled so small that it looks retina).

I've tried changing my avatar to my Gravatar and back to an uploaded image, and to an Identicon (I've never had a retina Identicon — some people do though) but none of these are retina.

What happened? How can I get my retina avatar back?

<sup>It's still retina in chat though…</sup>

Comment: The avatar in your profile looks identical to me in your chat profile, your meta profile and your main site profile. Tried flushing your browser cache? Shift-Reload?

Comment: @Ian Yes, I've tried other browsers too. Are you seeing it identical retina or identical normal?

Comment: I don't have a retina display. I see identical whatever resolution they are on my displays. Windows and Mac machines.

Answer (score 1):

I see a difference in Urls when I select them using F12 in Chrome.

This is your chat URL `https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYszY.png?s=128&g=1&g&s=32`
and this is your current (at least for me visible) question URL `https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYszY.png?s=32&g=1`

The URL is the same, but the s = size if I'm correct and might have something to do with it.

This was too long to comment, and I'm sorry if this does not point anyone in the right direction for solving the issue regarding your issue.

Comment: Indeed, I recently became aware of this (and forgot to add this to the question so thanks though) — definitely more curious why this is though.